# Anyone have the algorithm for determine if a hand of Mahjong game wins or not?

Tags: c++, algorithm, mahjong

I am reading some introduction of an ancient Chinese game called Mahjong (a bit like poker but far more complicated). I have been spending couple days in writing a program to determine if a given hand is a win hand or not. Do anyone have any idea or know where can I find the free code for that? I only need the part to determine win/lose, I am not looking for the entire project. Thanks.

Comment: The winner is determined (even in perfect play) by the discards of all players, and frequently there is no perfect choice for a discard. This leads to a lack of determinism.

Comment: Perhaps you might get more of an answer if you specified which variant.

Comment: @Marcin I think he is talking about a finding if a given hand is a wining hand that ends the game. This is indeed deterministic.

Comment: @ Dan, currently, an variant will do. I am not specifically any kind of mahjong but I will follow the easier one at first.

Comment: A nice answer is available on there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154960/algorithm-to-find-streets-and-same-kind-in-a-hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [**this**](http://code.google.com/p/py-mcr/) cool Python library that can be used for scoring of a Mahjong hand given a situation. I know you are working in C++, but since python is highly readable, even to non-python coders, maybe you'll be able to copy/paste and edit the relevant part so you'll be able to use them.

Hope that helps you in some way.

Comment: Ha, and as @Andreas Brinck commented, please remember to accept answers that helped you solve you'r problem.

Comment: Thanks Ido.Co, that's a good start. At least I have something to refer to.